# What's the best practice to have browser reset scroll position on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## Issue

I'm creating a fairly simple portfolio. I have a nav bar at the top, with a few nav links. One of these is an "About Me", and when clicked, will automatically prompt the page to jump to the html div section tag, with an element id of `#about-me`. The URL also changes, and appends the `#about-me` at the end.

When I refresh the page, the url remains the same, and thus, the page doesn't scroll back up to the top, and instead upon reload, shows the same position. I believe this is due to the browser automatically using the cache? (correct me if I'm wrong please)

What's the best way to handle this **properly**?

## Some Possible Solutions

1. When the DOM finishes loading and is ready to be manipulated, use the jQuery `.ready()` function to immediately invoke a function that will automatically set the `window.location.href` to the source URL, which would reset the scroll position.
2. Prevent the browser from caching. (I suppose there is a downside to this, especially if I want some other portion of my site to utilize cache later in the future?)

Comment: try  to use scrollTop:0 on load

Comment: save the scroll position into `localStorage` and access while page refresh

Comment: This behaviour is handled **properly** and has nothing to do with cache. `#about-me` is called an anchor and when provided browsers scroll page to it by design.

Comment: @lolbas Thank you, I understand that it is the proper behavior, however, I was under the impression that a page refresh would reload the entire DOM (including stylesheets and scripts), and thus, start with the original url. However, the page refresh starts with the original url appended with the id of the section my page last scrolled to. Should the URL not reset on a page refresh? Sorry if I am making this confusing.

Comment: Anchor is a valid part of a URL and it musn't be truncated upon refresh.

Comment: I suggest you change the question to ask "how" rather than ask for the "best practice" or "best way". Best practice questions invite opinion-based answers and are therefore liable to be closed as such.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a pretty simple answer to this, in case anyone was wondering. Preventing the event's default behavior will stop the url from adding the hash at the end, and then you'll have to add in code to have the scrolling work properly, since preventing the default behavior will also prevent the navigation link from working properly. But upon page refresh, the page will start at the top, so long as you omit adding the hash back at the end of the animate function.

From [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Just omit this line of code to in order to have page refresh 
        //start at the top of the page
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>
 <style>
body, html, .main {
    height: 100%;
}

section {
    min-height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#section2">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 2 Below</a>

<div class="main">
  <section></section>
</div>

<div class="main" id="section2">
  <section style="background-color:blue"></section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```